# Fast distance calculation in scipy and numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Let `A,B` be `((day,observation,dim))` arrays. Each array contains for a given day the same number of observations, an observation being a point with dim dimensions (that is dim floats). For every day, I want to compute the spatial distances between all observations in `A` and `B` that day.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

A, B = np.random.rand(50,1000,10), np.random.rand(50,1000,10)

output = []
for day in range(50):
    output.append(cdist(A[day],B[day]))
```

where I use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

Is there a faster way to do this? Ideally, I would like to get for `output` a `((day,observation,observation))` array that contains for every day the pairwise distances between observations in `A` and `B` that day, whilst somehow avoid the loop over days.

Comment: Rather than describing your data in words, you can write a short, runnable piece of code. If you make it so people can copy, paste and run the code in your question without undefined variables and other problems, then a) you will make your desired output crystal clear and b) you are more likely to get good answers. [Here's a recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31714641/553404)

Comment: Thanks, I added code for copy&paste

Comment: Thanks - I think that if the number of "days" is small relative to the number of observations, the overhead of the Python loop will be relatively insignificant compared to the `cdist` calculations.

Comment: @YXD Yes, I should have clarified. I'm interested in the case when all three dimensions are very large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it (though it will require a massive amount of memory) is to make clever use of array broadcasting:

```
output = np.sqrt( np.sum( (A[:,:,np.newaxis,:] - B[:,np.newaxis,:,:])**2, axis=-1) )
```

---

**Edit**

But after some testing, it seems that probably scikit-learn's [`euclidean_distances`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) is the best option for large arrays. (Note that I've rewritten your loop into a list comprehension.)

This is for 100 data points per day:

```
# your own code using cdist
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
%timeit dists1 = np.asarray([cdist(x,y) for x, y in zip(A, B)])

100 loops, best of 3: 8.81 ms per loop

# pure numpy with broadcasting
%timeit dists2 = np.sqrt( np.sum( (A[:,:,np.newaxis,:] - B[:,np.newaxis,:,:])**2, axis=-1) )

10 loops, best of 3: 46.9 ms per loop

# scikit-learn's algorithm
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
%timeit dists3 = np.asarray([euclidean_distances(x,y) for x, y in zip(A, B)])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

and this is for 2000 data points per day:

```
In [5]: %timeit dists1 = np.asarray([cdist(x,y) for x, y in zip(A, B)])
1 loops, best of 3: 3.07 s per loop

In [7]: %timeit dists3 = np.asarray([euclidean_distances(x,y) for x, y in zip(A, B)])

1 loops, best of 3: 2.94 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I would have thought the scikit distances would be just a wrapper for scipy distances but apparently they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'm an idiot and forgot that python's `map` is evaluated lazily. My "faster" code wasn't actually doing any of the work! Forcing evaluation removed the performance boost.

I think your time is going to be dominated by the time spent inside the scipy function. I'd use `map` instead of the loop anyway as I think its a bit neater but I don't think theres any magic way to get a huge performance boost here. Maybe compiling the code with cython or using numba would help a little.

Comment: Fantastic! I had already tried numba which also gave massive performance improvement. Though I still hope that there might be a direct numpy way to retrieve output as an array (without converting).

Comment: If you are using Python 3, `map` returns an iterator. If so, `map` is not evaluating `cdist` or anything when you are running it. Try printing  or inspecting `output`. In Python 2, where `map` is not lazy, the second method is marginally slower for large `n` :(