# Convert pandas sparse dataframe to sparse numpy matrix for sklearn use?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have some data, around 400 million rows, some features are categorical. I apply `pandas.get_dummies` to do one-hot encoding, and I have to use `sparse=True`option because the data is a little big(otherwise exceptions/errors are raised).

```
result = result.drop(["time", "Ds"], 1)
result_encoded = pd.get_dummies(result, columns=["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"], sparse=True)
```

Then, I get a sparse dataframe(result_encoded) with 9000 features. After that, I want to run a ridge regression on the data. At first, I tried to feed `dataframe.value` into sklearn,

```
train_data = result_encoded.drop(['count'].values)
```

but raised the error: "array is too big".
Then, I just fed sparse dataframe to sklearn, similar error message showed again.

```
train_data = result_encoded.drop(['count'])
```

Do I need to consider a different method or preparation of the data so it can be used by sklearn directly?

Comment: (Reposting an old comment) Rather than describing your data in words, you can write a short, runnable piece of code. If you make it so people can copy, paste and run the code in your question without undefined variables and other problems, then a) you will make your desired output crystal clear and b) you are more likely to get good answers. [Here's an example.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31714641/553404)

Comment: Check the `pandas` documentation for sparse frames.  I believe there's a method, possibly experimental, to produce a scipy sparse matrix.  I've answered a few questions on this, but don't have the links at hand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34185851/901925

Comment: I would consider using scikit's OneHotEncoder instead. The resulting sparse matrix can be directly used with scikits predictors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the experimental `.to_coo()` method in pandas [1] in the following way:

```
result_encoded, idx_rows, idx_cols = result_encoded.stack().to_sparse().to_coo()
result_encoded = result_encoded.tocsr()
```

This method, instead of taking a `DataFrame` (rows / columns) it takes a `Series` with rows and columns in a `MultiIndex` (this is why you need the `.stack()` method). This `Series` with the `MultiIndex` needs to be a `SparseSeries`, and even if your input is a `SparseDataFrame`, `.stack()` returns a regular `Series`. So, you need to use the `.to_sparse()` method before calling `.to_coo()`.

The `Series` returned by `.stack()`, even if it's not a `SparseSeries` only contains the elements that are not null, so it shouldn't take more memory than the sparse version (at least with `np.nan` when the type is `np.float`).

In general, you'll want to more efficient `CSR` or `CCR` format for your sparse scipy array, instead of the simpler `COO`, so you can convert it with the `.tocsr()` method.

1. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse